# What does a CFD infection do to a Magic user?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5

What occurs when a magic user (mage, adept, mystic adept, drake or pixie or some other metahuman species that has an inherent magic score) is infected with nanites hosting a CFD strain?

I have been thinking about this subject and have yet to find an answer in RAW, besides the fact that the nanites would probably lower their Essence and there for magic somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Using nanites does not lower the essence.

*Chrome Flesh, p. 146* contains rules regarding nanites:

> Nanoware does not carry an Essence cost [...]

Nanohives would cost you essence, since they are cyberware, but even without a hive you can use nanites at no essence cost; this is expensive however, since without a hive the rating of nanoware degrades by 1 per week. (CFD nanites are able to reproduce without a nanohive though.)

*Stolen Souls* does not mention losing the ability to do magic either, so there's no effect on the magical abilities of the host.

A CFD persona probably won't be able to use magic though, since most magical skills cannot be improvised.

Comment: Do you have a citation for CFD nanites not needing nanohives?

Comment: @TheAmusedMuse *Chrome Flesh, p. 148, Replicators box*, also *Stolen Souls*, p. 194 just below the Nanite Volume table. (I won't add this to the answer, since this seems like an irrelevant detail.) Also if you think about it, this property is absolutely necessary for the virus to make sense: For 5 in-game years the best you could do was stopping the progress of the infection. According to the rules after 2 months every single nanite in a host's body would be dead without a nanohive, so why not just deactivate the nanohives an wait. Also people can be infected, even if they don't have bodyware.